# Sort and Filter using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet

When using the pear Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer Library for PHP, is there a way to create an excel file with sort/filter (represented in recent Excel versions by the big A-Z Funnel Icon) headers activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer doesn't have any methods for setting filters.

Comment: Nor does PHPExcel support this for writing xls files, although it is supported for xlsx files